# BAD Request 404 while sending data through post method in spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Please check out my code and let me know what is the issue that is causing the below exception even though i am sending the data.

**JSp & Script**

```
                <td>
                <label for="shippingInstructions">shipping Instructions</label>
                <input type="text" id="shippingInstructions" onchange="detectedChange(this,${entryNumberHtml})"/>
            </td>
       

<script type="text/javascript">

function detectedChange(data,entry){
       var entryNum=entry.toString();
       var ins = data.value;
       console.log("xhr post request")
       $.ajax({
           url:config.encodedContextPath+"/cart/findShippingInstructions",
           data:JSON.stringify({ "entryCodes":entryNum,"shippingInstructions":ins }),
           datatype:"json",
           contentType:'application/json',
           type:"POST"
       })


    }
</script>
```

**The data it is sending through XHR**

`{"entryCodes":"0","shippingInstructions":"Hi"}`

**ControllerCode**

```
@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/findShippingInstructions", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public final Map<String, String> saveShippingInstructions(@RequestParam("entryCodes")
                                                              final String entryCodes, @RequestParam("shippingInstructions")
                                                              final String shippingInstructions)
    {
        final Map<String, String> shipInstructionsResult = new HashMap<>();
        try
        {
            final CartModel sessionCart = cartService.getSessionCart();
            trainingCartFacade.saveShippingInstructions(sessionCart, entryCodes, shippingInstructions);
            final TWCommerceCartParameter param = new TWCommerceCartParameter();
            param.setCart(sessionCart);
            param.setEnableHooks(true);
            commerceCartCalculationStrategy.recalculateCart(param);
            shipInstructionsResult.put("result", "reload");
        }
        catch (final Exception ex)
        {
            LOG.error("Exception occurred while storing  ");
            shipInstructionsResult.put("result", "do nothing");
        }
        return shipInstructionsResult;
    }
```

**Error i am getting**

```
 Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'entryCodes' is not present]
```

thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `@ResponseBody` you might as well create a structure/object  holding both your attributes `entryCode` and `shippingInstructions`in an `Instruction` for example :

```
@Data //Lombok Annotation
public class Instruction {
    @NotBlank
    private final String entryCode;
   @NotBlank
    private final String shippingInstructions;
}
```

this way you dont have to use requestParams and RequestBody together, which can lead to issues, and you have the @Valid annotation, like this

```
 public final Map<String, String> saveShippingInstructions ( @RequestBody @Valid Instruction instruction )`
```

Comment: Yes @Youri , i did the same, able to resolve when i faced that issue by creating a form POJO. Thanks so much. forgot to update this.

Comment: Glad to hear it !